# Input text wouldn't take autofocus after created dynamicaly on FF

Tags: jquery, firefox, autofocus

I click a span, an input text is created with `autofocus` attribute (I also tried with autofocus="focus").

on Chrome, Opera, Safari, and even IE, the input text take the autofocus but only Firefox doesn't take it (I tested on FF V 16 and 18)

I had to make the fallback for the other browsers anyway so I added th focus via jQuery, but still, FF wouldn't take it after the input is created.

That's how I added it via jQuery:

```
<span onclick=" createdTextInput('idOffline','edit'); 
$(function(){ $('#idOfCreatedInput').focus(); });" title=""> clickMe </span>
```

I'm calling focus() on the the new created Input after creating it.

I even tried with selectors like:

```
 $(function() {$('[autofocus]').focus()});
```

and

```
 $('input[type="text"]').focus();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it with a `setTimeout()` and selector on `autofocus` since with the input ID it didn't work..

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $("[autofocus]").focus(); 
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('#idOfCreatedInput').trigger('focus')
```

Comment: Im not familiar with "on" property, but it seems to me that your code is for executing something when my element gets focus, but what im trying to do is to get the focus on the newly created element

Comment: edit my answer, now whne you create it if you call trigger it focus

Comment: Thank you for your answer but nothing changed, it still refuses to get focus.. am I doing something wrong .. ?

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle? jsfiddle.net